# Attributes added using setAttribute aren't processed by the behavior

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, setattribute

For example if I am doing `a.setAttribute("begin", b+".focus");` it shows up in the HTML tab of the dev tool but it's completely ignored by the [behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531079%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (if I add `begin="time1.focus"` directly in the html it works just fine).

How do you expose these dynamically-added attributes to the behavior?
Is there another way to add them? (createElement and document.write excluded)

PS: I have already tried using createAttribute + nodeValue + setAttributeNode to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is the order: you need to set the attributes **before** adding the behavior's class or using [`addBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535922(v=vs.85).aspx).